# PrettyPhoto Jquery Lightbox link problems

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using the fantastic PrettyPhoto Lightbox, a Jquery lightbox clone.

To launch a lightbox with an iframe this is the code

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="Google.com opened at 100%">Google.com</a>
```

This works great!

The problem is that I am using javascript to make some of my div's links with this code

```
<div onclick="http://www.google.com?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" class="menuitem">
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I suspect that this is because DIV's do not support the rel attribute. Does anyone have any ideas on how to over come this?

Thanks for your help,

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out line 87 of the plugin js file (jquery.prettyPhoto.js)

```
$('a[rel*='+theGallery+']').each(function(i){
```

It is specifically looking for 'a' elements. You could look through the plugin and change a few things to make it work for your needs.

```
$('div[rel*='+theGallery+']').each(function(i){
```

I should add that I don't think rel is a valid div attribute. You may want to use a class or some other selectable attribute.