# Pretty Photo Set linking Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, lightbox

Yesterday a nice stack overflow user helped me to trigger the Jquery Prettyphoto Lightbox from a DIV element rather than an A element.

You can find that solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760891/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-link-problems)

This works... Almost.

Pretty Photo looks for all the links that reference it and then compiles them into a slideshow of iframes. Normally when you click on a link it will open up the iframe lightbox corresponding to the link i clicked on.

However with this new DIV solution it is opening up to the first iframe link it finds on the page, rather than the link I click on.

This must obviously be happening because I have altered the javascript call code from

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto[iframes]']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div[class^='prettyphoto[iframes]']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
```

I have been going through the other JS files but I am not a javascript programmer.

I am going to post the entire JS file. Maybe someone can see what javascript I need to change to make this DIV element work like an A element.

```
(function($) {
$.prettyPhoto = {version: '2.5.4'};

$.fn.prettyPhoto = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        animationSpeed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
        padding: 40, /* padding for each side of the picture */
        opacity: 0.80, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
        showTitle: true, /* true/false */
        allowresize: true, /* true/false */
        counter_separator_label: '/', /* The separator for the gallery counter 1 "of" 2 */
        theme: 'light_rounded', /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square */
        hideflash: false, /* Hides all the flash object on a page, set to TRUE if flash appears over prettyPhoto */
        modal: false, /* If set to true, only the close button will close the window */
        changepicturecallback: function(){}, /* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */
        callback: function(){} /* Called when prettyPhoto is closed */
    }, settings);

    // Fallback to a supported theme for IE6
    if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6){
        settings.theme = "light_square";
    }

    if($('.pp_overlay').size() == 0) {
        _buildOverlay(); // If the overlay is not there, inject it!
    }else{
        // Set my global selectors
        $pp_pic_holder = $('.pp_pic_holder');
        $ppt = $('.ppt');
    }

    // Global variables accessible only by prettyPhoto
    var doresize = true, percentBased = false, correctSizes,

    // Cached selectors
    $pp_pic_holder, $ppt,

    // prettyPhoto container specific
    pp_contentHeight, pp_contentWidth, pp_containerHeight, pp_containerWidth, pp_type = 'image',

    //Gallery specific
    setPosition = 0,

    // Global elements
    $scrollPos = _getScroll();

    // Window/Keyboard events
    $(window).scroll(function(){ $scrollPos = _getScroll(); _centerOverlay(); _resizeOverlay(); });
    $(window).resize(function(){ _centerOverlay(); _resizeOverlay(); });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if($pp_pic_holder.is(':visible'))
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37:
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
                break;
            case 39:
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
                break;
            case 27:
                if(!settings.modal)
                $.prettyPhoto.close();
                break;
        };
    });

    // Bind the code to each links
    $(this).each(function(){
        $(this).bind('click',function(){

            link = this; // Fix scoping

            // Find out if the picture is part of a set
            theRel = $(this).attr('rel');
            galleryRegExp = /\[(?:.*)\]/;
            theGallery = galleryRegExp.exec(theRel);

            // Build the gallery array
            var images = new Array(), titles = new Array(), descriptions = new Array();
            if(theGallery){
                $('a[rel*='+theGallery+']').each(function(i){
                    if($(this)[0] === $(link)[0]) setPosition = i; // Get the position in the set
                    images.push($(this).attr('href'));
                    titles.push($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
                    descriptions.push($(this).attr('title'));
                });
            }else{
                images = $(this).attr('href');
                titles = ($(this).find('img').attr('alt')) ?  $(this).find('img').attr('alt') : '';
                descriptions = ($(this).attr('title')) ?  $(this).attr('title') : '';
            }

            $.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);
            return false;
        });
    });


    /**
    * Opens the prettyPhoto modal box.
    * @param image {String,Array} Full path to the image to be open, can also be an array containing full images paths.
    * @param title {String,Array} The title to be displayed with the picture, can also be an array containing all the titles.
    * @param description {String,Array} The description to be displayed with the picture, can also be an array containing all the descriptions.
    */
    $.prettyPhoto.open = function(gallery_images,gallery_titles,gallery_descriptions) {
        // To fix the bug with IE select boxes
        if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6){
            $('select').css('visibility','hidden');
        };

        // Hide the flash
        if(settings.hideflash) $('object,embed').css('visibility','hidden');

        // Convert everything to an array in the case it's a single item
        images = $.makeArray(gallery_images);
        titles = $.makeArray(gallery_titles);
        descriptions = $.makeArray(gallery_descriptions);

        if($('.pp_overlay').size() == 0) {
            _buildOverlay(); // If the overlay is not there, inject it!
        }else{
            // Set my global selectors
            $pp_pic_holder = $('.pp_pic_holder');
            $ppt = $('.ppt');
        }

        $pp_pic_holder.attr('class','pp_pic_holder ' + settings.theme); // Set the proper theme

        isSet = ($(images).size() > 0) ?  true : false; // Find out if it's a set

        _getFileType(images[setPosition]); // Set the proper file type

        _centerOverlay(); // Center it

        // Hide the next/previous links if on first or last images.
        _checkPosition($(images).size());

        $('.pp_loaderIcon').show(); // Do I need to explain?

        // Fade the content in
        $('div.pp_overlay').show().fadeTo(settings.animationSpeed,settings.opacity, function(){
            $pp_pic_holder.fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed,function(){
                // Display the current position
                $pp_pic_holder.find('p.currentTextHolder').text((setPosition+1) + settings.counter_separator_label + $(images).size());

                // Set the description
                if(descriptions[setPosition]){
                    $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_description').show().html(unescape(descriptions[setPosition]));
                }else{
                    $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_description').hide().text('');
                };

                // Set the title
                if(titles[setPosition] && settings.showTitle){
                    hasTitle = true;
                    $ppt.html(unescape(titles[setPosition]));
                }else{
                    hasTitle = false;
                };

                // Inject the proper content
                if(pp_type == 'image'){
                    // Set the new image
                    imgPreloader = new Image();

                    // Preload the neighbour images
                    nextImage = new Image();
                    if(isSet && setPosition > $(images).size()) nextImage.src = images[setPosition + 1];
                    prevImage = new Image();
                    if(isSet && images[setPosition - 1]) prevImage.src = images[setPosition - 1];

                    pp_typeMarkup = '<img id="fullResImage" src="" />';             
                    $pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res')[0].innerHTML = pp_typeMarkup;

                    $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_content').css('overflow','hidden');
                    $pp_pic_holder.find('#fullResImage').attr('src',images[setPosition]);

                    imgPreloader.onload = function(){
                        // Fit item to viewport
                        correctSizes = _fitToViewport(imgPreloader.width,imgPreloader.height);

                        _showContent();
                    };

                    imgPreloader.src = images[setPosition];
                }else{
                    // Get the dimensions
                    movie_width = ( parseFloat(grab_param('width',images[setPosition])) ) ? grab_param('width',images[setPosition]) : "425";
                    movie_height = ( parseFloat(grab_param('height',images[setPosition])) ) ? grab_param('height',images[setPosition]) : "344";

                    // If the size is % based, calculate according to window dimensions
                    if(movie_width.indexOf('%') != -1 || movie_height.indexOf('%') != -1){
                        movie_height = ($(window).height() * parseFloat(movie_height) / 100) - 100;
                        movie_width = ($(window).width() * parseFloat(movie_width) / 100) - 100;
                        percentBased = true;
                    }

                    movie_height = parseFloat(movie_height);
                    movie_width = parseFloat(movie_width);

                    if(pp_type == 'quicktime') movie_height+=15; // Add space for the control bar

                    // Fit item to viewport
                    correctSizes = _fitToViewport(movie_width,movie_height);

                    if(pp_type == 'youtube'){
                        pp_typeMarkup = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="'+correctSizes['width']+'" height="'+correctSizes['height']+'"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+grab_param('v',images[setPosition])+'" /><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+grab_param('v',images[setPosition])+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="'+correctSizes['width']+'" height="'+correctSizes['height']+'"></embed></object>';
                    }else if(pp_type == 'quicktime'){
                        pp_typeMarkup = '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="'+correctSizes['height']+'" width="'+correctSizes['width']+'"><param name="src" value="'+images[setPosition]+'"><param name="autoplay" value="true"><param name="type" value="video/quicktime"><embed src="'+images[setPosition]+'" height="'+correctSizes['height']+'" width="'+correctSizes['width']+'" autoplay="true" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed></object>';
                    }else if(pp_type == 'flash'){
                        flash_vars = images[setPosition];
                        flash_vars = flash_vars.substring(images[setPosition].indexOf('flashvars') + 10,images[setPosition].length);

                        filename = images[setPosition];
                        filename = filename.substring(0,filename.indexOf('?'));

                        pp_typeMarkup = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="'+correctSizes['width']+'" height="'+correctSizes['height']+'"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="'+filename+'?'+flash_vars+'" /><embed src="'+filename+'?'+flash_vars+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="'+correctSizes['width']+'" height="'+correctSizes['height']+'"></embed></object>';
                    }else if(pp_type == 'iframe'){
                        movie_url = images[setPosition];
                        movie_url = movie_url.substr(0,movie_url.indexOf('iframe')-1);

                        pp_typeMarkup = '<iframe src ="'+movie_url+'" width="'+(correctSizes['width']-10)+'" height="'+(correctSizes['height']-10)+'" frameborder="no"></iframe>';
                    }

                    // Show content
                    _showContent();
                }
            });
        });
    };

    /**
    * Change page in the prettyPhoto modal box
    * @param direction {String} Direction of the paging, previous or next.
    */
    $.prettyPhoto.changePage = function(direction){
        if(direction == 'previous') {
            setPosition--;
            if (setPosition < 0){
                setPosition = 0;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            if($('.pp_arrow_next').is('.disabled')) return;
            setPosition++;
        };

        // Allow the resizing of the images
        if(!doresize) doresize = true;

        _hideContent();
        $('a.pp_expand,a.pp_contract').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed,function(){
            $(this).removeClass('pp_contract').addClass('pp_expand');
            $.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);
        });
    };

    /**
    * Closes the prettyPhoto modal box.
    */
    $.prettyPhoto.close = function(){
        $pp_pic_holder.find('object,embed').css('visibility','hidden');

        $('div.pp_pic_holder,div.ppt').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed);

        $('div.pp_overlay').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed, function(){
            $('div.pp_overlay,div.pp_pic_holder,div.ppt').remove();

            // To fix the bug with IE select boxes
            if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6){
                $('select').css('visibility','visible');
            };

            // Show the flash
            if(settings.hideflash) $('object,embed').css('visibility','visible');

            setPosition = 0;

            settings.callback();
        });

        doresize = true;
    };

    /**
    * Set the proper sizes on the containers and animate the content in.
    */
    _showContent = function(){
        $('.pp_loaderIcon').hide();

        if($.browser.opera) {
            windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        }else{
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            windowWidth = $(window).width();
        };

        // Calculate the opened top position of the pic holder
        projectedTop = $scrollPos['scrollTop'] + ((windowHeight/2) - (correctSizes['containerHeight']/2));
        if(projectedTop < 0) projectedTop = 0 + $pp_pic_holder.find('.ppt').height();

        // Resize the content holder
        $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_content').animate({'height':correctSizes['contentHeight']},settings.animationSpeed);

        // Resize picture the holder
        $pp_pic_holder.animate({
            'top': projectedTop,
            'left': ((windowWidth/2) - (correctSizes['containerWidth']/2)),
            'width': correctSizes['containerWidth']
        },settings.animationSpeed,function(){
            $pp_pic_holder.width(correctSizes['containerWidth']);
            $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_hoverContainer,#fullResImage').height(correctSizes['height']).width(correctSizes['width']);

            // Fade the new image
            $pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res').fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed);

            // Show the nav
            if(isSet && pp_type=="image") { $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_hoverContainer').fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed); }else{ $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_hoverContainer').hide(); }
            $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_details').fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed);

            // Show the title
            if(settings.showTitle && hasTitle){
                $ppt.css({
                    'top' : $pp_pic_holder.offset().top - 20,
                    'left' : $pp_pic_holder.offset().left + (settings.padding/2),
                    'display' : 'none'
                });

                $ppt.fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed);
            };

            // Fade the resizing link if the image is resized
            if(correctSizes['resized']) $('a.pp_expand,a.pp_contract').fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed);

            // Once everything is done, inject the content if it's now a photo
            if(pp_type != 'image') $pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res')[0].innerHTML = pp_typeMarkup;

            // Callback!
            settings.changepicturecallback();
        });
    };

    /**
    * Hide the content...DUH!
    */
    function _hideContent(){
        // Fade out the current picture
        $pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res object,#pp_full_res embed').css('visibility','hidden');
        $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_hoverContainer,.pp_details').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed);
        $pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed,function(){
            $('.pp_loaderIcon').show();
        });

        // Hide the title
        $ppt.fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed);
    }

    /**
    * Check the item position in the gallery array, hide or show the navigation links
    * @param setCount {integer} The total number of items in the set
    */
    function _checkPosition(setCount){
        // If at the end, hide the next link
        if(setPosition == setCount-1) {
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_next').css('visibility','hidden');
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_arrow_next').addClass('disabled').unbind('click');
        }else{ 
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_next').css('visibility','visible');
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_arrow_next.disabled').removeClass('disabled').bind('click',function(){
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
                return false;
            });
        };

        // If at the beginning, hide the previous link
        if(setPosition == 0) {
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_previous').css('visibility','hidden');
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_arrow_previous').addClass('disabled').unbind('click');
        }else{
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_previous').css('visibility','visible');
            $pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_arrow_previous.disabled').removeClass('disabled').bind('click',function(){
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
                return false;
            });
        };

        // Hide the bottom nav if it's not a set.
        if(setCount > 1) {
            $('.pp_nav').show();
        }else{
            $('.pp_nav').hide();
        }
    };

    /**
    * Resize the item dimensions if it's bigger than the viewport
    * @param width {integer} Width of the item to be opened
    * @param height {integer} Height of the item to be opened
    * @return An array containin the "fitted" dimensions
    */
    function _fitToViewport(width,height){
        hasBeenResized = false;

        _getDimensions(width,height);

        // Define them in case there's no resize needed
        imageWidth = width;
        imageHeight = height;

        windowHeight = $(window).height();
        windowWidth = $(window).width();

        if( ((pp_containerWidth > windowWidth) || (pp_containerHeight > windowHeight)) && doresize && settings.allowresize && !percentBased) {
            hasBeenResized = true;
            notFitting = true;

            while (notFitting){
                if((pp_containerWidth > windowWidth)){
                    imageWidth = (windowWidth - 200);
                    imageHeight = (height/width) * imageWidth;
                }else if((pp_containerHeight > windowHeight)){
                    imageHeight = (windowHeight - 200);
                    imageWidth = (width/height) * imageHeight;
                }else{
                    notFitting = false;
                };

                pp_containerHeight = imageHeight;
                pp_containerWidth = imageWidth;
            };

            _getDimensions(imageWidth,imageHeight);
        };

        return {
            width:imageWidth,
            height:imageHeight,
            containerHeight:pp_containerHeight,
            containerWidth:pp_containerWidth,
            contentHeight:pp_contentHeight,
            contentWidth:pp_contentWidth,
            resized:hasBeenResized
        };
    };

    /**
    * Get the containers dimensions according to the item size
    * @param width {integer} Width of the item to be opened
    * @param height {integer} Height of the item to be opened
    */
    function _getDimensions(width,height){
        $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_details').width(width).find('.pp_description').width(width - parseFloat($pp_pic_holder.find('a.pp_close').css('width'))); /* To have the correct height */

        // Get the container size, to resize the holder to the right dimensions
        pp_contentHeight = height + $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_details').height() + parseFloat($pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_details').css('marginTop')) + parseFloat($pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_details').css('marginBottom'));
        pp_contentWidth = width;
        pp_containerHeight = pp_contentHeight + $pp_pic_holder.find('.ppt').height() + $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_top').height() + $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_bottom').height();
        pp_containerWidth = width + settings.padding;
    }

    function _getFileType(itemSrc){
        if (itemSrc.match(/youtube\.com\/watch/i)) {
            pp_type = 'youtube';
        }else if(itemSrc.indexOf('.mov') != -1){ 
            pp_type = 'quicktime';
        }else if(itemSrc.indexOf('.swf') != -1){
            pp_type = 'flash';
        }else if(itemSrc.indexOf('iframe') != -1){
            pp_type = 'iframe'
        }else{
            pp_type = 'image';
        };
    };

    function _centerOverlay(){
        if($.browser.opera) {
            windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        }else{
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            windowWidth = $(window).width();
        };

        if(doresize) {
            $pHeight = $pp_pic_holder.height();
            $pWidth = $pp_pic_holder.width();
            $tHeight = $ppt.height();

            projectedTop = (windowHeight/2) + $scrollPos['scrollTop'] - ($pHeight/2);
            if(projectedTop < 0) projectedTop = 0 + $tHeight;

            $pp_pic_holder.css({
                'top': projectedTop,
                'left': (windowWidth/2) + $scrollPos['scrollLeft'] - ($pWidth/2)
            });

            $ppt.css({
                'top' : projectedTop - $tHeight,
                'left' : (windowWidth/2) + $scrollPos['scrollLeft'] - ($pWidth/2) + (settings.padding/2)
            });
        };
    };

    function _getScroll(){
        if (self.pageYOffset) {
            scrollTop = self.pageYOffset;
            scrollLeft = self.pageXOffset;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) { // Explorer 6 Strict
            scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
            scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
            scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft;  
        }

        return {scrollTop:scrollTop,scrollLeft:scrollLeft};
    };

    function _resizeOverlay() {
        $('div.pp_overlay').css({
            'height':$(document).height(),
            'width':$(window).width()
        });
    };

    function _buildOverlay(){
        toInject = "";

        // Build the background overlay div
        toInject += "<div class='pp_overlay'></div>";

        // Basic HTML for the picture holder
        toInject += '<div class="pp_pic_holder"><div class="pp_top"><div class="pp_left"></div><div class="pp_middle"></div><div class="pp_right"></div></div><div class="pp_content"><a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a><div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div><div class="pp_hoverContainer"><a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a><a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a></div><div id="pp_full_res"></div><div class="pp_details clearfix"><a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a><p class="pp_description"></p><div class="pp_nav"><a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a><p class="currentTextHolder">0'+settings.counter_separator_label+'0</p><a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a></div></div></div><div class="pp_bottom"><div class="pp_left"></div><div class="pp_middle"></div><div class="pp_right"></div></div></div>';

        // Basic html for the title holder
        toInject += '<div class="ppt"></div>';

        $('body').append(toInject);

        // So it fades nicely
        $('div.pp_overlay').css('opacity',0);

        // Set my global selectors
        $pp_pic_holder = $('.pp_pic_holder');
        $ppt = $('.ppt');

        $('div.pp_overlay').css('height',$(document).height()).hide().bind('click',function(){
            if(!settings.modal)
            $.prettyPhoto.close();
        });

        $('a.pp_close').bind('click',function(){ $.prettyPhoto.close(); return false; });

        $('a.pp_expand').bind('click',function(){
            $this = $(this); // Fix scoping

            // Expand the image
            if($this.hasClass('pp_expand')){
                $this.removeClass('pp_expand').addClass('pp_contract');
                doresize = false;
            }else{
                $this.removeClass('pp_contract').addClass('pp_expand');
                doresize = true;
            };

            _hideContent();

            $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_hoverContainer, .pp_details').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed);
            $pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed,function(){
                $.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);
            });

            return false;
        });

        $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_previous, .pp_arrow_previous').bind('click',function(){
            $.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
            return false;
        });

        $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_next, .pp_arrow_next').bind('click',function(){
            $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
            return false;
        });

        $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_hoverContainer').css({
            'margin-left': settings.padding/2
        });
    };
};

function grab_param(name,url){
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

})(jQuery);

[Here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#download) is the link to the lighbox.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Have you used an href element on the div?

Comment: No, I have used a javascript <div onclick="location.href='url'"></div>

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the pretty photos code is using the `rel` attribute explicitly, do your `div`'s have rel?  You are calling the code on `$("div[class^='menuitem[iframes]']").prettyPhoto();`

But then pretty photos is looking for `theRel = $(this).attr('rel');` and running against that.

Comment: Beggs, thanks firstly for posting.

Yes my divs have the rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]". Taking that away causes it stop working for divs. Changing the div's rel to a class, the calling code to a class and the js to theRel = $(this).attr('class'); lets prettyphoto work, but it still doesnt navigate to right iframe. This seems like such an abstract question (see revisions) so thanks so much for posting, my priority at the moment is to identify which code looks for the iframe links and which code makes sure the user is normally directed to the right iframe. All help is appreciated!